sphinx :includehidden: does not appear to work in the global toctree
I am attempting to create a global table of contents that is displayed in the left sidebar and that includes the contents of all subsidiary tables of content. My global table of contents is coded like this:
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 5
   :caption: Content
   :includehidden:

   using_website
   Concepts/ModernAmanuensis/ModernAmanuensisOrganization
   glossary

and the table of contents in my subsidiary tables is coded like this:
.. toctree::
   :hidden:
  
   Amanuensis/IdeasForAmanuensisSoftware

The directory structure is:
docs (directory)
  source (directory)
    index.rst
    ModernAmanuensis (directory)
      ModernAmanuensis.rst (including a subsidiary table of contents)
      Amanuensis (directory)
        IdeasForAmanuensisSoftware.rst (which includes a subsidiary table of contents)
        Contents (directory)
          Collections.rst

I must be doing something wrong but I have no idea what. Can anyone say how this should be done? I am using Sphinx 8.1.3 with the Sphinx_rtd_theme from ReadTheDocs.
